# how can I know the language of a character using PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, character

I want to differentiate the character if it is in Arabic or English?

How can I do that using PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **mb_detect_encoding** function to detect current character set for given string.Please read carefully this function before use.

Get info about this function from here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

You can also use header for set chracterset like

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');